# Not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-animations

I applied keyframes to my FadeIn const and want to wrap it around a div. Without the type it throws an error in the return when I wrap it. As far as I understand I need to apply the correct type so Typescript does not throw an error in my case. But still with React.ElementType or React.Component as type I cannot resolve the error.

What is the correct type to assign in this case?

The error message at `const FadeIn: React.ElementType`:

```
Type '"\n\n@keyframes fadeIn {\n    from {\n        opacity:0;\n    }\n    to {\n        opacity:1;\n    }\n  }\n"' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'.
```

**Simple function**

```
const FadeIn: React.ElementType = ` 

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
  }
`;

function Box() {
  return (
    <>
            <FadeIn>
              <div>...</div>
            </FadeIn>
          );

export default Box;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but FadeIn is a string that contains css code, it's not an element. Therefore you can also not use it as a component.

Comment: I want to create a styled component, like the #4 here - https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822
But without the additional styled-components library

Comment: You should then make FadeIn in a simlar way to Box, and apply styles to the html elements you want. And especially in the case of animations and such, you'd be better off moving your css to a separate file and importing that.

Comment: I know that I can make a separate css file and import it but in this particular case its not what I need to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @paddotk said, the value you want to assign to `FadeIn` is a string, so you cannot tell typescript this is going to be a React element.

That being said, this is not the right way to build your own styled components. That library use tagged template literals which is another way to call a function (but you cannot expect a string literal to become a function/component). So what you want is your `FadeIn component to be a React component that will be called using template literals`.

Here you have a complete post on how to build your own styled-components:

https://blog.logrocket.com/build-your-own-styled-components-library/

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said in the comments, React can't directly do what your case looks like, but you can do it with a css-in-js approach (if you want).

There's a great solution, and I saw you give an example of a Medium article

### Solution

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#animations

So, the changed code should be:

```js
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const FadeInKeyframes = keyframes`
  from {
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
`;

// It's a React Component
const FadeIn = styled.div` 
   animation: ${rotate} 2s linear infinite;
`;

function Box() {
  return (
    <>
      <FadeIn>
        <div>...</div>
      </FadeIn>
    </>
  );
}

export default Box;
```